# How to match a single character except when on a specific situation

Tags: java, regex, string, regex-lookarounds, string-matching

I have a string that I want to break into parts at every semicolon `;`.

I'm using JAVA `String.split(regex)` for that, creating an array of strings.

EXAMPLE:

```
string 1;
string 2;
string 3;
string 4 (
   substring 1;
   substring 2;
   substring 3;
);
string 4;
```

I'm using `line.split("\\s*;\\s*");` right now...

But that, as expected but not wanted, gives me back `["string 1", "string 2", "string 3", "string 4 (\nsubstring 1", "substring 2", "substring 3", ")", "string 4", ""]`.

So how do I match every `;` so I can split at it except for the ones inside the parenthesis (the ones after the substrings)?

EDIT:

I did manage to create a regex to match ";" inside the parenthesis, but not outside... but after using logic and converting `~(a^b)` to `~av~b` (de morgan law) I did make a regex to match ";" outside the parenthesis.

But it still doesn't work and still breaks in every semicolon... is it something with Java itself?

Current Pattern: `((?<![\S\s]*?\([\S\s]*?)|(?![\S\s]*?\)[\S\s]*?));`

Comment: `["string 1", "string 2", "string 3", "string 4 (substring 1; substring 2; substring 3)", "string 4", ""]`

Comment: Old fashoined logic here, but why not replace the `;` values between `(` and `)` (can use indexOf/substring) with another value, then replace all `;` then re-replace the values chnaged in step 1?

Comment: i'm actually trying it right now, but it isn't working. i'm checking on that, but I wanted to know if I could do it entirely in regex if I don't find what's wrong.

```game = game.replaceAll("(?<=.*\\(.*);(?=.*\\).*)", "$semicolon$");
  myStory.importStory(game, "\\s*;\\s*");```

is there a better way of replacing the value for sure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure some Java pros have much better solutions than regular expressions, yet this might be somewhat close to look into:

```
.*\((?:\s*(?:[^\r\n]*;)\s*)+\);|[^\r\n]+
```

I guess you'd likely want to `trim` and push it to an array.

#### Test

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class RegularExpression{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        final String regex = ".*\\((?:\\s*(?:[^\\r\\n]*;)\\s*)+\\);|[^\\r\\n]+";
        final String string = "string 1;\n"
             + "string 2;\n"
             + "string 3;\n"
             + "string 4 (\n"
             + "   substring 1;\n"
             + "   substring 2;\n"
             + "   substring 3;\n"
             + ");\n"
             + "string 4;\n"
             + "string 1;\n"
             + "string 2;\n"
             + "string 3;\n"
             + "string 4 (\n"
             + "   substring 1;\n"
             + "   substring 2;\n"
             + "   substring 3;\n"
             + ");\n"
             + "string 4;";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

#### Output

```
Full match: string 1;
Full match: string 2;
Full match: string 3;
Full match: string 4 (
   substring 1;
   substring 2;
   substring 3;
);
Full match: string 4;
Full match: string 1;
Full match: string 2;
Full match: string 3;
Full match: string 4 (
   substring 1;
   substring 2;
   substring 3;
);
Full match: string 4;
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/DksF0C/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/DksF0C/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
String[] array = line.split("(?<\!\\(.*[^)]);");
```

### Code Below:

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "string 1;" + 
            "string 2;" + 
            "string 3;" + 
            "string 4 (" + 
            "   substring 1;" + 
            "   substring 2;" + 
            "   substring 3;" + 
            ");" + 
            "string 4;";
    System.out.println(line);   
    System.out.println();


    String[] array = line.split("(?<!\\(.*[^)]);");
    System.out.println(
            Arrays.toString(array)); // Arrays.toString(Object[] a) converts an array to a printable string.


}
```

}

Prints:

string 1;string 2;string 3;string 4 (   substring 1;   substring 2;   substring 3;);string 4;

[string 1, string 2, string 3, string 4 (   substring 1;   substring 2;   substring 3;), string 4;]